# Are the configuration space registers mapped to memory space or IO space?

Tags: x86, hardware

I have read that each PCI device function have a set of registers referred to as *configuration space*, and this *configuration space* is 256 bytes long. And you can access these registers using the following two port-mapped I/O addresses:

```
CONFIG_ADDRESS 0x3f8
CONFIG_DATA 0x3fc
```

My question is, are the `configuration space` registers also mapped to memory space or IO space? or is the only way to access them is through `0x3f8` and `0x3fc`?

Comment: Don't spam tags. This is more of a hardware question. t definitively is not related to C or Assembly language nor OS.

Comment: Note that the correct addresses are 0xcf8 and 0xcfc.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom Can you answer my question, are these 256 bytes also mapped to memory space or IO space? or is the only way to access them is through `0xcf8` and `0xcfc`?

Comment: Konstantin already did, their answer is not only correct but also complete. The 256 bytes of legacy-PCI config space are neither IO nor memory mapped: you access them through those two registers (that are themselves in the IO address space). PCIe changes a few things as Konstantin pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

PCI config address space is indeed 256 bytes per device.  It was extended to 2K registers per device for PCIe, and old format of registers does not have space for the address bits.

PCIe mandates Enhanced Configuration Access Mechanism, which must be "a flat memory-mapped address space to access device configuration registers" on PC-compatible x86's. MCFG ACPI table provides the base address of the configuration registers mapping, and is described in the PCI firmware specification.

Practically, firmware selects the large (typically 256M is required to map all possible 256 buses) chunk of address space and configures north bridge accordingly.  Intel provides public processor datasheets for CPUs uncore where you can look up details.

For backward compatibility, initial configuration accesses or accesses to legacy (<= 255) config registers can be performed through CONFIG_A/D io ports.

Answer (score 3):

Let me explain this by showing few difference between PCI & PCI Express config space.
During the enumeration process BIOS access the config space to perform the initialization of the PCI devices. BIOS will have to first access the config space of the end point device inorder to set up the MMIO or IO address range for it (If device request for the MMIO or IO addresses via BAR registers to access its internal memory). 
Intel architecture provides two port address 0xCFC(config data port) & 0xCF8(config address port) to access the config space of the PCI device. BIOS writes BUS-DEVICE-FUNCION-CONFIG_REGISTER_OFFSET into 0xCF8 to access the particular register in config space, and the value of the register will be fetched from 0xCFC(config data port), These operations are done by invoking OUT and IN instruction. This mechanism of accessing configuration space registers is called Legacy/PCI configuration access mechanism.

The PCI provides 256 Bytes of config space, But is has been increased to 4KB for PCI Express devices. Now if you look at the address format of PCI config space mechanism you would see that 1 Byte has been given to provide the offset of the register you want to access in PCI config space. It will perfectly makes sense for PCI device since entire 256 bytes config space can be accessed in 1 bytes offset (256 entries). But in case of PCI Express devices only first 256 bytes of config space can be accessed through this mechanism, This mechanism will not support to access remaining PCIe config space!!!!

Now lets talk about the ECAM (Enhanced configuration access mechanism) which is used in PCI Express to access the config space of a PCIe device. In this mechanism the 4KB of config space will be mapped into the memory called memory mapped config, this mechanism will provide 12 bits for offset of the config registers you want to access.

To answer your question, Configuration space registers are mapped into memory space(MM config) only for PCI Express devices, not for PCI devices. The PCI config space will not be mapped into MMIO or IO address space, it will be accessed by two ports register as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Those are normal IO operations (using IN and OUT assembler commands). Even though it may be possible that hardware also maps those to MEM address space it is not worth to use it as legacy access to PCI must be supported by every PCI compliant hardware (we are talking about PC all the time).

Rule of the thumb - low addresses (below 0xFFFF) like those above are regular I/O, high addresses like 0xFFFFFFxx or 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFxxxx will be memory mapped IO.